# Using mix minify in directories

Tags: javascript, laravel, minify, laravel-mix

I'm trying to minify all my js files in my resources/js directly to the public/js after using the npm run prod command, i've read the documentation but apparently i can only do this by specifying each file on the mix.js array. Is there any way i can make the minification dynamical, where whenever a new js file is added, there would be no need to add it to the webpack.mix.js file?
The resources directory has subfolders too, I'm looking for a way to search the whole directory and when minified, copy the subfolder's architecture too

Comment: well, a quick way is to just include the js file by `require('file_path');` on one js file and include that file on the mix but it seems you want to add a specific js to specific views

Comment: Yes, the problem with me adding each file is that on every new js file i'll have to add it to the mix.js file, so I'm searching for an dynamical way to create the file and when the build happens, it already minifies it

Comment: what I suggested was just using the `require` method to include your individual js file on the app.js file and have a single script file that will do the trick the only downside is that the app.js file can be big you will have a minified build.

Comment: ahh i hadn't understood that solution, i'll try doing that, thank you :D